# im trying to count model object but its not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

**I'm trying to count model object using Django but it's not working, it doesn't display anything, that's the HTML code, I've tried both .all.count and .count but both aren't showing anything**

```
<div class="card">
        <div> <h3>Followers: {{profiles.follower.all.count}}</h3> </div>
        <div> <h3>Followings: {{profiles.following.count}}</h3> </div>
</div>
```

**And that's the python profile function code**

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    user_posts= post.objects.filter(user=user)
    profiles = Userprofile.objects.filter(user=user)
    context = {
        'user_posts':user_posts,
        'profiles': profiles
    }
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
```

**My Models **

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='maker')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True)

class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    follower = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True, related_name='follower')
    following = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True, related_name='following')
```

Comment: would you provide all necessary models

Comment: I did, that's everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the `.first()` in your views.py:

```
def profile(request, username):
    ....
    user_posts= post.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    profiles = Userprofile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    ......
```

Comment: the filter is return QuerySet[]. the  get_object_or_404  is return Instance, so if you don't use .first() you have use {{ % for <> in <> % }} in your .html.